# ¿Cómo tomar los datos del formulario Checkout Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce, checkout

Estoy intentando usar un API de facturación para que al realizar la compra y este pase a “Completado” automáticamente se realice la factura y se envié por correo al cliente.
Estoy usando el hook 'woocommerce_order_status_completed' para que al pasar a ese status se envíen los datos, al hacerlo de forma manual (con un formulario HTML y un PHP para la petición al API) se crea la factura sin problemas, pero al hacerlo desde Woocommerce me envía el error de que los datos están vacíos. He intentado usar $_REQUEST en lugar de $_POST pero sin resultados.
El código que estoy usando es:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed',  'getData', 10, 1);

function getData($order_id) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
}
//Aquí empieza la peticion
use Facturapi\Facturapi;

require_once 'facturapi/src/Facturapi.php';

$facturapi = new Facturapi( "token acceso" );


$customer = $facturapi->Customers->create([
"email" => "$_POST[billing_email]",
  "legal_name" => "$_POST[billing_first_name]",
  "tax_id" => "$_POST[rfc_input]",
  "address" => array(
  "zip"=> "$_POST[billing_postcode]",
  "street" => "$_POST[billing_address_1]",
  "exterior" => "$_POST[billing_address_2]",
    "neighborhood" => "$_POST[billing_city]"
)
]);
```